# Drop values below group means with Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a DataFrame/Series with multiple indices. Here's a code to generate one:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'd', 'd']], names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.Series(range(16), index=index)
```

"s" becomes:

```
In [139]: pd.Series(range(16), index=i2)
Out[139]: 
first  second
a      c          0
       c          1
       d          2
       d          3
       c          4
       c          5
       d          6
       d          7
b      c          8
       c          9
       d         10
       d         11
       c         12
       c         13
       d         14
       d         15
dtype: int64
```

How to drop values which are below the group means (originally 20% of group means)?

```
In [140]: s.mean(level=[0,1])
Out[140]: 
first  second
a      c          2.5
       d          4.5
b      c         10.5
       d         12.5
dtype: float64
```

The "dumb" way would be to cycle through the frame (iterrows) and compare one by one. There must be a smarter, Pandas way like using something like apply/join/whatever. 
I'm quite new to Pandas.

Comment: "drop values which are below the group means" Which group?  The first or second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `transform` for this:

```
>>> s.loc[s >= s.groupby(level=[0,1]).transform("mean")]
first  second
a      c          4
       c          5
       d          6
       d          7
b      c         12
       c         13
       d         14
       d         15
dtype: int64
```

`transform` takes the groupby reduction result, here `mean`, and expands it up to match the original index, which means we can use it to create a boolean mask:

```
>>> s.groupby(level=[0,1]).transform("mean")
first  second
a      c          2.5
       c          2.5
       d          4.5
       d          4.5
       c          2.5
[and so on]
>>> s >= s.groupby(level=[0,1]).transform("mean")
first  second
a      c         False
       c         False
       d         False
       d         False
       c          True
[and so on]
```

I might also write simply `s.groupby(s.index).transform("mean")`, but that's more an issue of preference than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it, using [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
s.groupby(level=[0,1], group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g[g > g.mean()])
```

I'll break it down:  `groupby` divides your series using your MultiIndex levels.  The parameter `[0,1]` tells pandas to group using both the first and second MultiIndex levels, and `group_keys=False` prevents pandas from duplicating the indices in the final output.

`.apply( ... )` then applies a function to each group.  In this case, your function is so simple that you can use a one-line [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) function.  `lambda g: g[g < g.mean()]`) uses normal pandas syntax for applying a logical expression to a series. In this case, we tell it to get all members of `g` (the subset of your series, grouped by levels one and two of your MultiIndex) where the value is less than the group mean (`g.mean()`).

```
In [1]: s.groupby(level=[0,1], group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g[g > g.mean()])
Out[1]:
first   second
a       c       4
        c       5
        d       6
        d       7
b       c       12
        c       13
        d       14
        d       15
```

Comment: That's also good. It's a pity I can't mark both of them as a solution.

Comment: Thanks!  I voted for the other one as well; I think it's a neater solution.  Hopefully this one will help people who come with a similar but not necessarily identical problem.